# Youtube Data API Access Not Configured

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have this error when trying to recover an endpoint on youtube api.

> Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 602077678805 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=602077678805 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.',

This is image console configuration
[image]

This is image com http return
[image]

Comment: Log in with the same account you used to ask the question to be able to edit without approval and comment on your questions and their answers.

Answer (score -1):

> Access Not Configured.

This error message can mean  you have not enabled the api for use in your project.  In order to use an API you must tell google that you intend to use it in your project.  You cant just create a project and automatically use all of the apis google would like to know which ones you intend to use.

Go to the google developer console for your project as instructed in the link.  under Libraries search for YouTube API enable it and apply for a quota.

[image]

[image]